# Force engine=innodb when using Entity Framework Code First with mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have created a new .NET MVC 5 web application using Entity Framework 6 and a msyql database.  I am using code/model first.  The database server has a default storage engine of MyISAM, but I would like for the tables that EF creates to be InnoDb.  Does anyone know if there is as way to specify the storage engine that EF will use in the **CREATE TABLE** statement?

Comment: Are you asking how to modify the migrations? You can pass an anonymous object with extra arguments to ]DbMigration.CreateTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration.createtable(v=vs.113).aspx), eg `new { SampleArgument = "MyValue" }`. Perhaps you can pass `new { Engine = "INNODB" }`

Comment: [@Devart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135566/devart)'s [dotConnect for MySQL](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/) provides a `MySqlCreateTableConfiguration` class that enables one to specify a storage engine within `CreateTable` operations in Code-First Migrations.

Answer (score 6):

Actually the engine used by MySQL EF provider is ALWAYS InnoDB and you can't change it without rewriting the DDL generator.

To try you can create a simple project and enable log on MySQL. You will notice that every create statement will terminate with `engine=InnoDb auto_increment=0`

For example this class

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

with standard MySQL EF provider migration, generates this MySQL DDL statement

```
CREATE TABLE `Blogs` (
    `BlogId` INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `Name` NVARCHAR(200),
    `Topic` NVARCHAR(200),
    `LastUpdated` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `Order` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`BlogId`)
    ) engine = InnoDb auto_increment = 0
```

Where is `engine = InnoDb` from? It's hard coded in migration source code.
You can have a look at the migration source code
https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/6.9/Source/MySql.Data.EntityFramework5/MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.cs
method `MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(CreateTableOperation op)`.
The last statement is `sb.Append(") engine=InnoDb auto_increment=0");`

So, the right question should be how can I change the engine from InnoDB to another engine.
You can inherit MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator class and override the method, i.e.:

```
internal class MyOwnMigrationSqlGenerator : MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator
{

    public MyOwnMigrationSqlGenerator()
    {
        Engine = "InnoDB";
    }

    public MyOwnMigrationSqlGenerator(string engine)
    {
        Engine = engine;
    }




    private readonly List<MigrationStatement> _specialStatements = new List<MigrationStatement>();

    public string Engine { get; set; }

    public override IEnumerable<MigrationStatement> Generate(IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> migrationOperations, string providerManifestToken)
    {
        List<MigrationStatement> migrationStatements = base.Generate(migrationOperations, providerManifestToken).ToList();
        migrationStatements.AddRange(_specialStatements);
        return migrationStatements;
    }

    protected override MigrationStatement Generate(CreateTableOperation op)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string tableName = TrimSchemaPrefix(op.Name);
        var autoIncrementCols = (List<string>)(typeof(MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator).GetProperty("autoIncrementCols", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(this));
        var primaryKeyCols = (List<string>)(typeof(MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator).GetProperty("primaryKeyCols", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(this));


        sb.Append("create table " + "`" + tableName + "`" + " (");


        if (op.PrimaryKey != null)
        {
            op.PrimaryKey.Columns.ToList().ForEach(col => primaryKeyCols.Add(col));
        }


        //columns 
        sb.Append(string.Join(",", op.Columns.Select(c => "`" + c.Name + "` " + Generate(c))));


        // Determine columns that are GUID & identity 
        List<ColumnModel> guidCols = new List<ColumnModel>();
        ColumnModel guidPk = null;
        foreach (ColumnModel columnModel in op.Columns)
        {
            if (columnModel.Type == PrimitiveTypeKind.Guid && columnModel.IsIdentity && String.Compare(columnModel.StoreType, "CHAR(36) BINARY", true) == 0)
            {
                if (primaryKeyCols.Contains(columnModel.Name))
                    guidPk = columnModel;
                guidCols.Add(columnModel);
            }
        }


        if (guidCols.Count != 0)
        {
            var createTrigger = new StringBuilder();
            createTrigger.AppendLine(string.Format("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `{0}_IdentityTgr`;", TrimSchemaPrefix(tableName)));
            createTrigger.AppendLine(string.Format("CREATE TRIGGER `{0}_IdentityTgr` BEFORE INSERT ON `{0}`", TrimSchemaPrefix(tableName)));
            createTrigger.AppendLine("FOR EACH ROW BEGIN");
            foreach (ColumnModel opCol in guidCols)
                createTrigger.AppendLine(string.Format("SET NEW.{0} = UUID();", opCol.Name));
            createTrigger.AppendLine(string.Format("DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmpIdentity_{0};", TrimSchemaPrefix(tableName)));
            createTrigger.AppendLine(string.Format("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpIdentity_{0} (guid CHAR(36))ENGINE=MEMORY;", TrimSchemaPrefix(tableName)));
            createTrigger.AppendLine(string.Format("INSERT INTO tmpIdentity_{0} VALUES(New.{1});", TrimSchemaPrefix(tableName), guidPk.Name));
            createTrigger.AppendLine("END");
            var sqlOp = new SqlOperation(createTrigger.ToString());
            _specialStatements.Add(Generate(sqlOp));
        }


        if (op.PrimaryKey != null) // && !sb.ToString().Contains("primary key")) 
        {
            sb.Append(",");
            sb.Append("primary key ( " + string.Join(",", op.PrimaryKey.Columns.Select(c => "`" + c + "`")) + ") ");
        }


        string keyFields = ",";
        autoIncrementCols.ForEach(col => keyFields += (!primaryKeyCols.Contains(col) ? string.Format(" KEY (`{0}`),", col) : ""));
        sb.Append(keyFields.Substring(0, keyFields.LastIndexOf(",")));
        sb.Append(string.Format(") engine={0} auto_increment=0", Engine));

        return new MigrationStatement() { Sql = sb.ToString() };
    }

    private string TrimSchemaPrefix(string table)
    {
        if (table.StartsWith("dbo.") || table.Contains("dbo."))
            return table.Replace("dbo.", "");


        return table;
    }

}
```

Then, in your migration configuration you can specify your own sql generator.

```
internal sealed class MyContextMigrationConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyContext>
{
    public MyContextMigrationConfiguration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MyOwnMigrationSqlGenerator("MyPreferredEngine"));
    }

}
```

**EDIT**
There was a bug on MyOwnMigrationSqlGenerator class. Probably the best thing is to rewrite all MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator. In this case I just fixed the class accessing private fields of MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator (that is quite bad).